# Duplicate entries with different timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Table for Customers by name : `Customer_SCD` in SQL 
I have 3 Columns present in it : `Customer_Name`, `Customer_ID` `Customer_TimeStamp`

There are duplicate entries in this table with different **Timestamp**.

For example

```
ABC, 1, 2012-12-05 11:58:20.370

ABC, 1, 2012-12-03 12:11:09.840
```

I want to eliminate this from the database and keep the first time/date available.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by eliminate? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Once you've tidied up, remember to add a unique constraint (or maybe multiple ones) to the table so that you don't have to do this job again in 6 months time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, try it:

```
DELETE  Customer_SCD
OUTPUT  deleted.*
FROM    Customer_SCD b
JOIN    (
    SELECT  MIN(a.Customer_TimeStamp) Customer_TimeStamp,
            Customer_ID,
            Customer_Name
    FROM    Customer_SCD a
    GROUP   BY a.Customer_ID, a.Customer_Name
) c ON 
    c.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID
AND c.Customer_Name = b.Customer_Name
AND c.Customer_TimeStamp <> b.Customer_TimeStamp
```

In a subquery it determines which record is the first one for every `Customer_Name`,`Customer_ID` and then it deletes all the other records for a duplicate. I also added the `OUTPUT` clause which returns rows affected by the statement.

You could also do it by using ranking function `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
DELETE  Customer_SCD
OUTPUT  deleted.*
FROM    Customer_SCD b
JOIN    (
    SELECT  Customer_ID,
            Customer_Name,
            Customer_TimeStamp,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID, Customer_Name ORDER BY Customer_TimeStamp) num
    FROM    Customer_SCD
) c ON 
    c.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID
AND c.Customer_Name = b.Customer_Name
AND c.Customer_TimeStamp = b.Customer_TimeStamp
AND c.num <> 1
```

See which one has a smaller query cost and use it, when I checked it, first approach was more efficient (it had a better execution plan).

Here's an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70fe3/1/0)**

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you the results you want to keep.

```
Select Customer_Name, Customer_ID, MIN(Customer_TimeStamp) as Customer_TimeStamp
from Customer_SCD 
group by Customer_Name, Customer_ID
```

store the result in a table variable, say `@correctTbl`

then join with this table and remove duplicates

```
delete 
from Customer_SCD a
inner join @correctTbl b on a.Customer_Name = b.Customer_Name and a.Customer_ID = b.Customer_ID and a.Customer_TimeStamp != b.Customer_TimeStamp
```