# How to solve SQLite error `near "bogus_table": syntax error: `?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm doing project where I have a table which has `hash` and `timestamp` columns. And the task is to delete all the rows which are `hash` duplicates, leaving the ones with oldest `timestamp`. I found a similar question on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927890/duplicate-entries-with-different-timestamp) and I tried to adopt the given snippet to my needs, but I got an error in sqlite
`near "shop_bogus": syntax error:`

My adopted snippet:

```
DELETE  shop_bogus
FROM    shop_bogus b
JOIN    (
    SELECT  MIN(a.timestamp) timestamp,
            hash
    FROM    shop_bogus a
    GROUP   BY a.hash
) c ON
    c.hash = b.hash
AND c.timestamp <> b.timestamp
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting duplicate rows from sqlite database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190541/deleting-duplicate-rows-from-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0):

The answer you ripped the statement from is for MS SQL Server; SQLite doesn't support this syntax for [DELETE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html).

Comment: Oh, is it even possible to make such query within sqlite or mysql db?

Comment: @МихаилПавлов Have you tried searching for "sqlite delete duplicates"?

Comment: Yes; didn't work for questioners who refuse to read, understand, or doing their part.

Comment: look what an awesome answer I got on reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnSQL/comments/4mx5nu/need_help_with_building_query/